# Close a question on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Is it possible to close a question I've asked on StackOverflow if I no longer require a response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just [3 more rep points](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and you can close your own questions.

If you have found an answer to your question though, you should answer it yourself to help people with the same problem in the future (will probably help with the rep as well :)).

Comment: Ah okay thanks, I didn't realise it was a case of needing more rep. Thanks deceze!